# XOR Crypt with Linux & Windows different

Tags: java, linux, windows, encryption

currently I'm programming a chat with XOR-Encryption. But today i encountered a problem. The encryption is under Windows different as in Linux. Under Linux the chat runs normally, but under Windows not.

Here the class:

```
class XOR_c {
    private boolean active = true;
    private int key;

    // Constructor
    public XOR_c(int k){
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No encryption!","Client", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
            this.active = false;
        }

        key = k;
    }

    public String encode(String s) {
        if (active == false) return s;

        char[] c = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++)
            c[i] = (char)(c[i]^key);

        return new String(c);
    }

    public String decode(String s){
        return encode(s);
    }


}
```

This is tested with openSuse, Debian and Windows 7.

Now how to fix it (At this moment I made a bypass for the encryption but this is not my target, I want a encryption with both systems)? Is my source wrong?

Comment: `System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")` is true on Windows machines, so it disables your encryption explicitly.  Do you have some other code that either removes this code path or uses another approach?

Comment: Having xor encryption is like have no encryption. Do you know that?

Comment: can you give an example of what's going wrong on windows? i.e. when you encode "abc" with new XOR_c(42) and then decode it with the same XOR_c, does it not return "abc"?

Comment: @Makoto: This is my currently attempt to fix the bug on Windows. The behaviour of this command is clear.  




Luka Rahne: Sure, I know. But this is for a school project and only for demonstration.  




user829755: After the decode of previously encoded Strings is correct when it is both on Windows. But when I encode the string 'abc' on Windows and want to decode it on Linux I doesn't work.

Comment: I would guess it is something to do with the default types of ``int`` or ``char`` but without concrete examples of input and output we'll never know :)

Comment: no, I don't think that's the reason because `^` is a bitwise operation, so the non-char bits of the key should just have no effect. but you could double-check by changing the type of key to char.

Comment: can you provide us with examples of the string "abc" encoded (we should rather say "obfuscated") on both platfroms with the same key?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess this is an encoding issue: the charset might be different on windows and linux. I'd suggest

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(charset);
...
return new String(bytes, charset)
```

, where `charset` is some explicit charset.

Comment: The end of line is also flagged differently in Windows and Linux.  Windows uses `\r\n` (0x0F 0x0C) while Linux uses just `\n` (0x0C).

Comment: @rossum I don't think that's the problem because the restored text would look almost right. on the other hand when one encoding always uses 16 bit and the other 8 bit, then the restored string looks like garbage. btw \r is 0x0D and \n is 0x0A